# Cannot make HDMI and hibernation work with GTX920m on Dell laptop 7559

Tags: nvidia, hdmi

I was given this laptop and trying to make it work with HDMI. I get some app crashes when the laptop resumes from hibernation, but for now I am focusing on making HDMI work. I have tried all drivers from [this list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EL8Fn.png) but nothing seems to work. I am using Ubuntu 15.10 with Gnome3. When I connect the HDMI cable to a monitor, I get a black blinking screen on both monitors. After it fails a few times, I need to take the cable off and restart x.

Something relevant might be this, in dmesg:

```
[  455.231422] CPU: 0 PID: 4270 Comm: Xorg Tainted: P        W  OE   4.2.0-23-generic #28-Ubuntu
[  455.231423] Hardware name: Dell Inc. Inspiron 7559/0H0CC0, BIOS 1.1.3 11/05/2015
[  455.231427]  0000000000000000 0000000014617fc5 ffff88027638f308 ffffffff817e94c9
[  455.231429]  0000000000000000 ffff88027638f360 ffff88027638f348 ffffffff8107b3d6
[  455.231431]  ffff88027638f410 ffff88027638f4b4 ffff880277a21000 ffff880277a20000
[  455.231431] Call Trace:
[  455.231437]  [<ffffffff817e94c9>] dump_stack+0x45/0x57
[  455.231442]  [<ffffffff8107b3d6>] warn_slowpath_common+0x86/0xc0
[  455.231445]  [<ffffffff8107b465>] warn_slowpath_fmt+0x55/0x70
[  455.231458]  [<ffffffffc0175b9e>] skl_update_other_pipe_wm+0x1de/0x1f0 [i915]
[  455.231470]  [<ffffffffc0175d6b>] skl_update_wm+0x1bb/0x740 [i915]
[  455.231494]  [<ffffffffc01c1837>] ? gen9_read32+0xf7/0x2d0 [i915]
[  455.231508]  [<ffffffffc01794be>] intel_update_watermarks+0x1e/0x30 [i915]
[  455.231533]  [<ffffffffc01e0f68>] haswell_crtc_enable+0x488/0xa90 [i915]
[  455.231556]  [<ffffffffc01ddd96>] __intel_set_mode+0x916/0xb60 [i915]
[  455.231578]  [<ffffffffc01e4b06>] intel_crtc_set_config+0x2b6/0x580 [i915]
[  455.231596]  [<ffffffffc00774a6>] drm_mode_set_config_internal+0x66/0x100 [drm]
[  455.231604]  [<ffffffffc011a692>] restore_fbdev_mode+0xc2/0xf0 [drm_kms_helper]
[  455.231611]  [<ffffffffc011c549>] drm_fb_helper_restore_fbdev_mode_unlocked+0x29/0x70 [drm_kms_helper]
[  455.231617]  [<ffffffffc011c5b2>] drm_fb_helper_set_par+0x22/0x40 [drm_kms_helper]
[  455.231640]  [<ffffffffc01f21aa>] intel_fbdev_set_par+0x1a/0x60 [i915]
[  455.231643]  [<ffffffff814482b6>] fb_set_var+0x236/0x460
[  455.231646]  [<ffffffff816bfd0c>] ? pci_conf1_read+0xbc/0x100
[  455.231649]  [<ffffffff816bfd0c>] ? pci_conf1_read+0xbc/0x100
[  455.231711]  [<ffffffffc068f2e6>] ? os_acquire_spinlock+0x16/0x30 [nvidia]
[  455.231715]  [<ffffffff8143e512>] fbcon_blank+0x312/0x360
[  455.231818]  [<ffffffffc0b594c9>] ? _nv015796rm+0x609/0x6f0 [nvidia]
[  455.231822]  [<ffffffff814d3d93>] do_unblank_screen+0xd3/0x1a0
[  455.231825]  [<ffffffff814c927a>] vt_ioctl+0x50a/0x12f0
[  455.231828]  [<ffffffff811ddac6>] ? __slab_free+0xb6/0x2c0
[  455.231831]  [<ffffffff814bc55c>] tty_ioctl+0x3cc/0xbc0
[  455.231835]  [<ffffffff811a7641>] ? kzfree+0x31/0x40
[  455.231837]  [<ffffffff811de046>] ? kfree+0x126/0x130
[  455.231840]  [<ffffffff81210aa5>] do_vfs_ioctl+0x295/0x480
[  455.231844]  [<ffffffff8121d9a4>] ? mntput+0x24/0x40
[  455.231846]  [<ffffffff811ff120>] ? __fput+0x190/0x220
[  455.231849]  [<ffffffff81210d09>] SyS_ioctl+0x79/0x90
[  455.231854]  [<ffffffff817f02b2>] entry_SYSCALL_64_fastpath+0x16/0x75
[  455.231855] ---[ end trace 48af455133ff453e ]---
[  455.490629] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20150619/nsarguments-95)
[  455.582303] vgaarb: this pci device is not a vga device
[  455.584332] ACPI Warning: \_SB_.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP._DSM: Argument #4 type mismatch - Found [Buffer], ACPI requires [Package] (20150619/nsarguments-95)
```

And my lspci is like:

```
lspci | grep 'VGA\|NVIDIA'
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 191b (rev 06)
02:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107M [GeForce GTX 960M] (rev a2)
```

Any help will be appreciated!